# Tab Bar hide while using the with Story board Id

Tags: ios, swift

**Hi,** In my project I used tab bar option but tab bar is hiding the while I click the back button.I use the dismiss function to close the Viewcontroller it's working for me.

**using dismiss function:**

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Using with identifier:**

```
let storageSizeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "hostview")
        self.present(storageSizeVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but some case it  repeatedly calls the between the two view controller while using dismiss function

**Sample screenshot:**

***while using the dismiss function:*** 
[image: while using the dismiss]
***while using identifier:***
[image: while using identifier]

if anyone knows ping me ...

Comment: Add some more code to understand

Comment: where you are  written this code ?

Comment: I wrote this code in inside the back button action

Comment: what code you need exactly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is, could you maybe reformulate?

Comment: if any alternative function for dismiss function for calling the  view controller

Comment: Is the question related to why there is not tabbar in your presented controller?

Comment: I don't have any idea about this issue and I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I honestly have some difficulty understanding what your issue is. Could you maybe edit your question with another explanation maybe more code or more screenshots? That would be great!

Comment: I want to show the tab bar in the all the view controllers